# How to read Facebook post based on updated time using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to read Facebook comments based on updated time through API?

I tried "since" and "until" but both are reading the data based on created time.

for example let us assume a user created a post on his timeline two days back and someone commented on the post today. If I try to read the comment done on today using the following query */me/feed?since=2014-09-08* it doesn't return anything because the created date is two days back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API search using since updated\_time parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818119/facebook-graph-api-search-using-since-updated-time-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

There's unfortunately no way to query the Graph API concerning the upate timestamp IMHO. `since` and `until` reference the `created_time`, as you said.

If you have a Graph API v2.0 app, you could theoretically use FQL to query by comment creation timestamp. Have a look at the `comment` table at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/ and the field `time`. I guess you'd have to in conjunction with the `stream` table to get the `post_is` list.

To be able to use FQL you'll need an app which is an Graph API v2.0 app. And FQL will only work until April 30th 2016.

Comment: Thanks Tobi. Let me try FQL.