# Facebook Graph API search using since updated_time parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API in Python. Every post has two datetimes:

1. `created_date`
2. `updated_date`

When I am providing the `since` parameter, it is returning feeds where the `created_date` is greater than or equal to the `since` parameter. For example, if I provide  `since=2015-06-05` then it will return all the posts from 5th June, 2015 to now.

But suppose there is a post that was posted on 7th June, 2015 and few activities (likes, shares, comments, etc.) that happened on 8th June, 2015. In this scenario the `updated_time` of that post changes but `created_time` will be the same (7th June, 2015). If I pass parameter `since=2015-06-08`, then I won't be able to track all of the activity on that post.

Is there any solution by which I can pass the `since` parameter on `updated_time` instead of passing it to `created_time`?

Comment: No, that is not possible. The API currently offers very limited filtering capabilities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [@CBroe points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818119/facebook-graph-api-search-using-since-updated-time-parameter/31280140#comment49688403_30818119), this isn't supported by the Facebook Graph API. (It was previously supported using [Facebook Query Language (FQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language), but that's no longer available).

That said, with some creativity (and a bit extra code) a similar effect can be achieved by combining a couple of queries.

In my application, I perform a query with the following parameters:

- `until=2015-07-07` (or whatever the `since` date would have been)
- `fields=updated_time` (to keep the query fast and the payload small)
- `limit=5000` (or some similarly large page size, as I'm only grabbing one field)

I then evaluate each post that has an `updated_time` greater than the would-be `since` date, and throw those posts into a queue to download the entirety of the post content.

So, for example, if the `until` (and, thus, `since`) date is `2015-07-07` but the `updated_time` on an individual post is `2015-10-15`, then I know that post was *created* prior to `2015-07-07` but *updated* afterwards. It won't get picked up in a `since` query, but I can easily download it individually to synchronize my cache.

> *Note:* If you're dealing with content where there are frequent updates on past content, you'd likely want to use the Graph API's [Batch Requests feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests), as opposed to downloading each post individually.

Comment: Can you share a sample code that does this along with how to update the database ?

Answer (score 2):

If the aim of your application is to react to changes on a given page or feed, consider using [Webhooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/) instead of manually crawling the page for updates.

> Webhooks allows you to receive real-time HTTP notifications of changes to specific objects in the Facebook Social Graph.